# scrape AWS ECS and store summary in S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

This is my scraper for AWS ECS (Elastic Container Service).  My primary use for this is to `grep` through the resulting file to see which cluster a given service is in.

I've been coding in python for a few years now, but I don't feel like my code is as pythonic as it should be.  I've run this though `pylint` and it passes cleanly now.  I'm open to any suggestions for how to make this cleaner, more reliable, or more pythonic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""scrape ECS for inventory"""

import pprint # pylint: disable=unused-import
import sys
import time
import boto3 # pylint: disable=import-error
import sre_logging

def ecs_services(ecs):
    """get all ECS services"""

    # get list of clusters from AWS
    ecs_clusters = []
    paginator1 = ecs.get_paginator('list_clusters')
    for page in paginator1.paginate():
        for cluster in page['clusterArns']:
            ecs_clusters.append(cluster)

    service_map = {}
    for cluster in ecs_clusters:
        # describe cluster
        cluster_details = ecs.describe_clusters(clusters=[cluster])
        cluster_name = cluster_details['clusters'][0]['clusterName']
        cluster_tags = cluster_details['clusters'][0]['tags']
        logger.info("getting services for cluster %s, tags: %s...", cluster_name, cluster_tags)
        service_map[cluster_name] = {}

        # get services
        paginator2 = ecs.get_paginator('list_services')
        this_ecs_services = []
        for page in paginator2.paginate(cluster=cluster):
            for service in page['serviceArns']:
                this_ecs_services.append(service)

        #pp.pprint(this_ecs_services)
        for service in this_ecs_services:
            service_details = ecs.describe_services(cluster=cluster, services=[service])
            service_name = service_details['services'][0]['serviceName']
            service_definition = service_details['services'][0]['taskDefinition']
            service_map[cluster_name][service_name] = {
                "serviceArn": service,
                "clusterArn": cluster,
                "taskDefinition": service_definition
            }

    return service_map

def find_consul(env):
    """pull consul variables out of environment"""
    #pp.pprint(env)

    host = ''
    port = ''
    prefix = ''
    for entry in env:
        if entry['name'] == 'CONSUL_HOST':
            host = entry['value']

        if entry['name'] == 'CONSUL_PORT':
            port = entry['value']

        if entry['name'] == 'CONSUL_SERVICE_PREFIX':
            prefix = entry['value']

    if prefix:
        consul_url = "%s:%s/%s" % (host, port, prefix)
    else:
        consul_url = "undefined"
    return consul_url

def scrape_ecs_stats():
    """do one pass of scraping ECS"""
    ecs = boto3.client('ecs')
    services = ecs_services(ecs)

    #pp.pprint(services)
    logger.info("getting task definitions...")

    # find consul config
    result_txt = []
    for cluster in services:
        for service in services[cluster]:
            task_def_arn = services[cluster][service]["taskDefinition"]
            task_def = ecs.describe_task_definition(taskDefinition=task_def_arn)
            env = task_def['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['environment']
            consul_url = find_consul(env)
            result_txt.append("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (cluster, service, task_def_arn, consul_url))

    send_content = "".join(result_txt)
    #pp.pprint(send_content)

    # upload to S3
    bucket = "redacted"
    filepath = "ecs/ecs_services.txt"
    boto_s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    boto_s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Body=send_content, ContentType="text/plain", Key=filepath)
    logger.info("sent %s to s3", filepath)

def main():
    """main control loop for scraping ECS stats"""
    while True:
        try:
            start = time.time()
            scrape_ecs_stats()
            end = time.time()
            duration = end - start
            naptime = 600 - duration
            if naptime < 0:
                naptime = 0

            logger.info("ran %d seconds, sleeping %3.2f minutes", duration, naptime/60)
            time.sleep(naptime)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(1)
        except: # pylint: disable=bare-except
            # so we can log unexpected and intermittant errors, from boto mostly
            logger.exception("top level catch")
            time.sleep(180) # 3 minutes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = sre_logging.configure_logging()
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Scraping?

Scraping should be the last resort for getting data from a service that does not have an [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). Thankfully, not only does ECS have a full API, you're using it via Boto - which means that you are not scraping. Scraping is hacking together unstructured content into structured data, which is not what you're doing.

### Comprehensions

```
ecs_clusters = []
paginator1 = ecs.get_paginator('list_clusters')
for page in paginator1.paginate():
    for cluster in page['clusterArns']:
        ecs_clusters.append(cluster)
```

can be

```
ecs_clusters = [
    cluster
    for page in paginator1.paginate()
    for cluster in page['clusterArns']
]
```

### Temporary variables

```
cluster_details['clusters'][0]
```

should receive a variable since it's used multiple times.

### Logging

I want to call out that you're using logging properly, and that's not nothing. Good job; keep it up.

### Interpolation

```
"%s:%s/%s" % (host, port, prefix)
```

can be

```
f"{host}:{port}/{prefix}"
```

### Successive string concatenation

As these things go, `"".join(result_txt)` is not the worst way to do concatenation. It's generally guaranteed to be more performant than `+=`. That said, I consider the `StringIO` interface to be simpler to use than having to manage and then aggregate a sequence, and it has the added advantage that you can more readily swap this out with an actual file object (including, maybe, an HTTP stream) if that's useful.

### Maxima

```
        naptime = 600 - duration
        if naptime < 0:
            naptime = 0
```

can be

```
naptime = max(0, 600 - duration)
```